# I want to send html type in email body with gmail sender

Tags: android, html, email

i want to send email using html code.
plzz help

GMailSender m = new GMailSender("", "");

```
    String[] toArr = {""};
    m.setTo(toArr); // load array to setTo function
    m.setFrom("dawinderg@gmail.com"); // who is sending the email 
    m.setSubject("Registration"); 
    m.setBody("Thanks for registration with us.");
```

i want to send

#### +username+

this code in m.setBody().
how can i do this??

Comment: Try to use Html.fromHtml().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
m.setBody(Html.fromHtml("<h1>Title</h1><br>Username "+ username +" and password"));
```

You can also create html tables or any other html elements

If the example is from here: [GMailSender example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Change

`DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));`

with`DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/html"));`

and add the body like this:

```
m.setBody("<html><h1>TESTING<h1></html>");
```

Comment: if i use this then this shows error.
because my setBody function having return type String.

Comment: 2 min I will return with example :)

Comment: I search a bit before I start the demo project and 1 question for you:
Are you using the class example in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a
If yes the solution is simple:)

Comment: ohk thxxx alot

here is my setbody and get body function

public String getBody() { 
  return _body; 
 } 
 
 public void setBody(String _body) { 
  this._body = _body; 
 }

Comment: here is my send function

MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 
   msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));  
   InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
   for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
    addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
   }
msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);  
   msg.setSubject(_subject); 
   msg.setSentDate(new Date());
   BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
   messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
   _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
 

   msg.setContent(_multipart); 

   Transport.send(msg);

Comment: yes the string there is ok but you need to change the encoding type: until now it was "text/plain" you need to change it to "text/html" :)

Comment: u know how to attach printer with appto print the bill??
and how to upload image into database with json and show into the listview??

Comment: Well for the moment I will give you only some ref links: Json send image: http://geekonjava.blogspot.de/2014/03/upload-image-on-server-in-android-using.html. Oh and almost forgot if the answer was usefull +1 please or if the answer was what you where locking for please mark it as correct :). Thanks

Comment: If I will have time today I will try to make a simple app demo with your request from above(printer and json) cheers

Comment: bro one more help i need
i have a project like whats app but i d'nt know how to start it and how it's working..... please help yr

Comment: where are you bro???
is it possible that send image with img src tag of html in above email method??